# How do you set Windows 7 photo viewer as default on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-association

I've tried searching and I've used registry edits but I can't select and use the Windows 7 Image Viewer application as my default.

Our end users hate the Windows 10 one and apparently, Microsoft has made it next to impossible to use their own control panel to change it back.

Comment: Tried the REG fix [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-windows-photo-viewer-windows-10/)? This adds WPV to Default Apps (and classic Default Programs) from where you can set it as the default.

Comment: Tried that. Won't allow the changes.

Comment: Despite the error message, WPV should still appear in Default Apps. Does it show up there?

Comment: It does. But you can't set anything

Comment: Tried Control Panel > Default Programs, as in Timmy Jim's answer below?

Comment: Yep. It won't accept them. If I set default by right click I can do it one by one.

Answer (score 1):

For machines that were **upgraded from a previous version of Windows** you should be able to do this:

Search "default programs" in the search feature, click "set your default programs", find "Windows Photo Viewer" on the left  (I believe this is the application you are talking about as the Windows 7 photo viewer), click on it, then click "Set this program as default."

Open a picture and it should open up in the Windows Photo Viewer.

If the machine **has Windows 10 installed from scratch**, you can try [this article](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-get-windows-photo-viewer-back-in-windows-10/) and follow the instructions under the "If you installed Windows 10 from scratch" section.

Basically, you will have to copy the registry code from [this post by Edwin](http://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/8930-windows-photo-viewer-gone-2.html#post290818) into notepad and save the file as a `.reg`.  Save it in a place where you can find it!  After that, open the newly made `.reg` file to merge it with your Registry (more dialogue boxes may appear to do this).  Then you should be able to follow the steps above for setting the default programs.

Comment: I'm sorry but this will not work on windows 10. By default the Photo Viewer is not activated and needs to be activated first.

Comment: If you upgraded windows 8.1 to Windows 10, it is upgraded too. But if the upgrade fails, or it is a fresh install (most likely otherwise OP would not have posted the question) the Windows Photo Viewer is not present on the system.

Comment: @LPChip that would explain why I still have it on my machine then.  I found a way [here](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-get-windows-photo-viewer-back-in-windows-10/) that may work for new machines under the installed from scratch part of the article.

Comment: Indeed, that is exactly what I'm talking about. If you can edit these instructions into your post, I'll gladly vote it up. :)

Comment: I've editted my answer to include both methods to fix this.  Goodluck!

Comment: I've been searching for a way to do this for a long time. The upgrade part would explain why I was able to find Photo Viewer on my laptop with ease, but could never get it to work on my desktop. I've been too lazy to mess with the registry, but it seems like it's the only option available.